# Declaring global commands inside a NPM package

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm try to understand how to declare a command inside a NPM package accessible through the main application.

For instance, I released a project inside the NPM registry, with a couple of commands inside the `package.json` like:

```
"scripts": {
 "somestuff": "node index.js"
},
```

Let say now I want to use this command `somestuff` inside the main app. When I try to run this I receive: `missing script: somestuff`.

Because is not defined inside the `package.json` of the main app but it's inside the `package.json` of the module inside the `node_modules` folder.

How can I declare a command inside a node module accessible from the main app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I think you can do something like this. In your `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  ...
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": "index.js",
  ...
}
```

Then invoke it from wherever you installed it as a dependency:

```
npx my-package
```

You would probably want to install `my-package` with `--save-dev`.

Also, have a look at [`npx-run` project](https://github.com/nearmap/npx-run), it looks exactly as what you want.